# how to continuously click on button to show next element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a bootstrap table with 3 hidden rows. I have a button that I want to click to show the row. I have this working but I want to add functionality so that when i click that button again the next row shows and click it one more time and the third hidden row shows. Is it possible to do this based off this function?

```
 <table id = "mt" class="tableManager-table-bordered"   
  <thead class = "thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th data-field="#">#</th>
      <th data-field="CurrentAnnouncements">Current Announcements</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class = "row5" id = "row5">
      <th data-field="#">5</th>
      <td class = "An5">Announcement 5</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class = "row6 id ="row6">
      <th data-field="#">6</th>
      <td class = "An6">Announcement 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "row7" id ="row7">
      <th data-field="#">7</th>
      <td class = "An7">Announcement 7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<button  type = "button" id = "crtbtn" class = "CreateAnnouncement">
Create Announcement
</button>
```

```
$(function () {
        $("#crtbtn").on('click', function () {
            $("#row5").show();

        });
    });
```

Comment: When the next row shows, does it mean the previous one will be hidden again? Can you provide the html structure?

Comment: I would like the previous one to still show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do the job:

```js
$(function () {
  const alltrs=$("#container tr").hide();
  $("#crtbtn" ).click(ev=>alltrs.filter(':hidden:first').show());
  $('#hideall').click(ev=>alltrs.hide());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="crtbtn">show more</button>
<button id="hideall">hide all again</button>
<table id="container">
    <tr class = "r5" id = "r5">
      <th data-field="#">5</th>
      <td class = "An5">Announcement 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "r6">
      <th data-field="#">6</th>
      <td class = "An6">Announcement 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "r7">
      <th data-field="#">7</th>
      <td class = "An7">Announcement 7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can do the same thing also without jQuery. Admittedly, a little more verbose, but it is still fairly short and clear:

```js
const alltrs=[...document.querySelectorAll("#container tr")],
      hideall=ev=>alltrs.forEach(t=>t.style.display="none");
hideall();
document.getElementById("crtbtn" ).onclick=ev=>{
  alltrs.some(t=>t.style.display=='none'? !(t.style.display="") : false) }
document.getElementById('hideall').onclick=hideall;
```

```html
<button id="crtbtn">show more</button>
<button id="hideall">hide all again</button>
<table id="container">
    <tr class = "r5" id = "r5">
      <th data-field="#">5</th>
      <td class = "An5">Announcement 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "r6">
      <th data-field="#">6</th>
      <td class = "An6">Announcement 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "r7">
      <th data-field="#">7</th>
      <td class = "An7">Announcement 7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`alltrs.some(t=>t.style.display=='none'? !(t.style.display="") : false) }` goes through all `<tr>`s until it finds one that has `t.style.display=="none"`. In that case it sets the same property to a blank (`""`) and returns `true` (`= !""`) thereby ending the `.some()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can just show the next element after the last shown element -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table').find('tr').slice(1).hide();
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('#table').find('tr:visible').next().show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button">
Show
</button>
```